# How can I maintain a global information in a spark cluster?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, global

It looks like information in Spark is rely on SparkContext.

If it stop(application is over, and call `sc.stop()`), all information about this application will disappear.

My question is, how can I maintain some information permanently(from Spark cluster start till cluster stop.)?

For example, I want to calculate MD5 of every application's jar file. I have tried to add a new class in spark source code to maintain this information. But each time a new application is submitted, this class will be initialized, so the information can not be reserved.

I also tried to add a `HashMap` in object `org.apache.spark.depoly.master.Master`(I thought this is alive in all cluster's lifetime), but even in this way, it will be initialized every time a new application is submitted.

So, how can I maintain a global information in Spark cluster? Create a new class(how and where)? or add a `Map` member(in which class or object)?

Comment: what about writing the information to some persistence layer? database, filesystem...

Comment: persistence layer will help, but it may brought some other problems. actually, I want to make a RDD durable across applications(`persist()` can not do this), so i thought it is better maintain this information inside spark cluster.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do that in "vanilla" spark. You might want to take a look at https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver: it allows you to give your RDDs a global name and to reuse them across different jobs...

Comment: RDDs are tied to applications. What you want is impossible, so you should think again. Just write to a persistence layer.

Answer (score 0):

The way to make an RDD durable across application instances is to save it to the filesystem using e.g. `saveAsObjectFile()`